# How do you test a submit button being disabled after clicking in capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, browser, capybara

We are trying to disable a certain submit button *after* clicking on it. Something like this:

```
assert !page.has_css?("#review_button[disabled='disabled']")
click_button "Review"
assert page.has_css?("#review_button[disabled='disabled']")
```

The problem, of course, is that the form submits before the second assertion is checked. Is there any way to disable the actual submission of the form, or suspend it until after the second assertion is checked?

Answer (score 1):

I remember having this same issue and never found a good way to do this, because as you said, it only gets to the next assert when the "Review" action completes.

What I ended up doing, considering that the action that the button did took a long time (and thus justifies having the button be disabled) is to make the action create a Delayed Job job and then let it run asynchronously. Then it's pretty easy to mock that out and make it sleep for a few seconds (or what have you) to check that the button is disabled.

Comment: What might the code for the `Delayed Job` job look like, and where does it go? Sorry to ask a basic one, but I'm quite new to capybara testing.